# Inequality with a rational function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, polynomials, rational-functions

Let $0< a_1\leq a_2\leq a_3\leq a_4\leq a_5$. Define the function $$f(x,y,z)=\cfrac{(a_1(x+y+z)^3+a_2(x)^3+a_3(x+y)^3+a_4(y+z)^3+a_5(z)^3 )^2}{(a_1(x+y+z)^2+a_2(x)^2+a_3(x+y)^2+a_4(y+z)^2+a_5(z)^2 )^3}.$$
Show that for all $x,y,z\in \mathbb R$ we have $f(x,y,z)\leq \cfrac{1}{a_1+a_2+a_3}.$

*Information about the problem:*

1. The function forms an asymptote at $\cfrac{1}{a_1+a_2+a_3}$.
2. We have $f(1,0,0)=\cfrac{1}{a_1+a_2+a_3}$.
3. As a function of $x$, it seems there are only three critical points. Same for $y$ and $z$.
4. Perhaps it helps to show that
   $$\cfrac{(a_1(x+y+z)^3+a_2(x)^3+a_3(x+y)^3+a_4(y+z)^3+a_5(z)^3 )^2}{(a_1(x+y+z)^2+a_2(x)^2+a_3(x+y)^2+a_4(y+z)^2+a_5(z)^2 )^3}\leq \cfrac{(a_1(x+y+z)^3+a_2(x)^3+a_3(x+y)^3+a_3(y+z)^3+a_3(z)^3 )^2}{(a_1(x+y+z)^2+a_2(x)^2+a_3(x+y)^2+a_3(y+z)^2+a_3(z)^2 )^3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer.**

First, I would like to give the equivalent problem:

*Problem 1*: Let $0 < a_1 \le a_2 \le a_3 \le a_4 \le a_5$. Let $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$a_1(x+y+z)^2+a_2x^2+a_3(x+y)^2+a_4(y+z)^2+a_5z^2 = a_1 + a_2 + a_3.\tag{1}$$ Prove that
$$a_1(x+y+z)^3 + a_2x^3 + a_3(x+y)^3 + a_4(y+z)^3 + a_5z^3 \le a_1 + a_2 + a_3.$$
Remark: The constraint (1) is an ellipsoid.

Second, if $x, y, z$ is non-negative, the inequality is true as Lemma 1 stated. One may use the Buffalo Way to prove Lemma 1 (easily with computer). So, if one can prove that the optimal $x, y, z$ in the original problem are non-negative, the desired result follows.

*Lemma 1*: Let $x, y, z\ge 0$ not all zero. Then
$$\frac{(a_1(x+y+z)^3 + a_2x^3 + a_3(x+y)^3 + a_4(y+z)^3 + a_5z^3)^2}{(a_1(x+y+z)^2+a_2x^2+a_3(x+y)^2+a_4(y+z)^2+a_5z^2)^3}
\le \frac{1}{a_1+a_2+a_3}.$$

Comment: Even with computers I don't see an easy way to solve Lemma 1. In fact using Lagrangian multipliers the computer returns enourmous expressions. More than 30 gigantic polynomials that are hard to solve.

Comment: Using the Buffalo Way, it is easy job to prove Lemma 1. Indeed, let $a_2 = a_1+s,  a_3 = a_1+s+t, a_4 = a_1+s+t+r, a_5 = a_1+s+t+r+p; s, t, r, p\ge 0$. There are some cases: (1) $z \le y\le x$: Let $y = z+ u, x = z + u + v; u, v\ge 0$. Then we need to prove that $f(a_1, s, t, r, p, z, u, v)\ge 0$ where $f$ is a polynomial with non-negative coefficients. (2) $z\le x\le y$: $\cdots\cdots$

Comment: Take $a_1=1, a_2=2, a_3 =3, a_4=4, a_5=5$ for example. Use Lagrange multipliers, the system about $(x,y,z,\lambda)$ has $14$ real roots according to Maple RealRootCounting command. On the other hand, to find the stationary points of the original problem,
for the case $x\ne 0$ (so let $x=1$), the system about $(y,z)$ has $5$ real roots. Usually, we need to check all these candidates for optimum. When $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$ are not given specific values, it seems complicated.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, to simplify, take the sixth root of $f$ to give $$g(x,y,z)=\frac{(a_1(x+y+z)^3+a_2x^3+a_3(x+y)^3+a_4(y+z)^3+a_5z^3)^{1/3}}{(a_1(x+y+z)^2+a_2x^2+a_3(x+y)^2+a_4(y+z)^2+a_5z^2)^{1/2}}$$ which is the ratio of a weighted 3-norm to its 2-norm. Notice also that the function is homogeneous in $x,y,z$, so one can divide the numerator and denominator by any scalar, $$g(x,y,z)=\frac{(a_1+a_2X^3+a_3(X+Y)^3+a_4(1-X)^3+a_5(1-X-Y)^3)^{1/3}}{(a_1+a_2X^2+a_3(X+Y)^2+a_4(1-X)^2+a_5(1-X-Y)^2)^{1/2}}$$ where $X=x/(x+y+z)$, $Y=y/(x+y+z)$.

A complete solution will take up too much space but here's the main idea. Suppose you want to maximize $(\alpha U^3+\beta V^3)^{1/3}/(\alpha U^2+\beta V^2)^{1/2}$, with $\alpha<\beta$, then that is the same as maximizing $$\alpha U^3+\beta V^3\qquad \mathrm{such\ that} \qquad \alpha U^2+\beta V^2=1.$$ If you use Lagrange multipliers, we find $$3\alpha U^2=2\lambda\alpha U,\qquad 3\beta V^2=2\lambda\beta V$$ so either $U=0,V=\beta^{-1/2}$, or $U=\alpha^{-1/2},V=0$, or $U=V=(\alpha+\beta)^{-1/2}$. The function evaluated at each of these points is equal to $\beta^{-1/6}$, $\alpha^{-1/6}$, $(\alpha+\beta)^{-1/6}$ respectively. The maximum is the middle one, with $U\ne0,V=0$. In general, *the components associated with the largest coefficients need to be made $0$*.

Back to the main problem, we need to make $1-X-Y=0$, so $X+Y=1$; then also $1-X=0$, so $X=1$. Hence $X=1$, $Y=0$, which is the same as $y=0$, $x=x+y+z$, so $z=0$. Any vector of the form $(x,0,0)$ will achieve the maximum value.

Comment: How do we know we need to make $1-X-Y=0$ and $1-X=0$ without solving the system of quadratic equations? I have a more general inequality with a bigger system to solve.

Comment: See the model problem. The actual solution would need to solve the quadratic equations like you said, but if you try a simpler problem, you may see a method. These types of problems are not easy in general.

Comment: The model problem is trivial. The prescribed problem is not. It is not true that 1-X-Y must be 0. There are more critical points at the maximum.